# Soft hyphens in XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, textblock, word-wrap, hyphenation

does anybody have an idea whether it is possible to define "soft hyphens" or "soft linebreaks" in e.g. a TextBlock's text? Background: I would like to use TextWrapping="Wrap" on a TextBlock, but normally that won't do anything if the text contained in the TextBlock does not contain white space.

E.g.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="OneVeryLongWordThatDoesNotContainAnyWhiteSpaceAtAll" />
```

won't wrap if there is insufficient space. So I thought maybe there is a way to tell TextWrapping where the text may be wrapped.

I tried using the HTML `&shy;` (soft hyphen) entity, but this is not allowed in XAML apparently (won't compile).

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex,

what do you mean by "won't wrap if there is insufficient space"? I tried your example code and it actually **does** wrap (it will break on every single character if necessary) when adding `Width="100"` or limiting by it's margins etc.

Setting width to 100 i get the following result:

> OneVeryLongWor
>   dThatDoesNotCon
>   tainAnyWhiteSpa
>   ceAtAll

When you limit the height (like `Height="20"`), it won't actually break of course, but you can add `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` to get a result like this:

> OneVeryLongW...

But oh well, it doesn't answer your question about Soft Hyphens, they obviously don't work.

Best regards =)

Comment: Right! It does actually wrap - problem was actually the surrounding container and its width settings...
Still it would be nice to have the possibility to determine where the line breaks are actually inserted instead of having the letter-wise wrapping behavior only.
But thanks, nerd :)

Comment: I wanted to write a behavior for you but now you already accepted :) JK. But beside having the Gui beeing ready for soft hyphens, i see more problems having your texts "softhyphonized" automatically. Need a dictionary here or a complex ruleset? or a combination?